# angular 2 - TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I am new to Angular.While running angular code,getting below error in console.

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'colourPreference' of undefined
    at AppComponent.get [as colour] (app.component.ts:22)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:443)
    at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:359)
```

**app.componenet.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserPreferencesService } from './UserPreferences.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>This is the home page</h1>
  <div>
  Colour preferences:
  <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='colour' [style.background]='colour'/>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constuctor(private _userPreferencesService: UserPreferencesService){

  }
  get colour():string{
    return this._userPreferencesService.colourPreference;
  }

  set colour(value: string){
    this._userPreferencesService.colourPreference=value;
  }
 }
```

**UserPreferences.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserPreferencesService{
colourPreference: string ='orange';
}
```

Is anyone have the solution for above problem.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `UserPreferencesService` included in your module's `providers` array?

Comment: @UncleDave yes it is included

Comment: You have a typo, `constuctor` instead of `constructor`. If that is present in the real code that's your issue.

Comment: @UncleDave Thank you